# Compare arraylist value and update MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist

I am using MySQL with Java, I have arraylist with some values, and I have MySQL table with some column.
Example:

```
Arraylist valAry = new ArrayList();
valAry.add('25');
valAry.add('28');
```

Table value:

Existing new table may be

```
**newtable**
id  val1  min_val1  max_val1  val2 min_val1  max_val1  time_stamp
 1   24      9         24       27     14        35     2014-03-27 15:06:00
```

From that I want to check the **newTable** with my current arraylist and update the newtable values.

```
id  val1  min_val1  max_val1  val2 min_val1  max_val1  time_stamp
 1   25      9         25       28     14        35     2014-03-27 15:07:00
```

Here I have listed just 2 values in arraylist, in future it may go 5 or 15 or 30, what ever it may be, like the the table columns will be auto generated.

So using single query comparison update statement to update table.

Comment: please clarify your Question.do you want to compare values frm 2 arrayList and the insert on that basis into new table?

Comment: what are you asking for?

Comment: Well, go ahead and do it.

Comment: No A5l-lE5. only one arraylist values needs compare with mysql newtable  column values and update that table of the value through mysql Query.

Comment: Finally i am looking for single query to check and update the table

Comment: Harri i have updated the question...

Comment: Sorry, Not able to understand what are you asking ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried following method to update the table from java end it works.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);
sb.append("update newtable set ");
for(int g=0;g<valAry.size();g++){

    sb.append("val1 =").append(valAry.get(g)).append(", min_val1 = IF (min_val1 <").append(valAry.get(g)).append(", min_val1 , ").append(valAry.get(g)).append(") , max_val1 = IF (max_val1 > ").append(valAry.get(g)).append(", max_val1 , ").append(valAry.get(g)).append("),");

}

sb.append("time_stamp = '").append(time_stamp).append("' where id = 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update table 
set val1=valAry.get(new Integer.valueOf(25)) and val2=valAry.get(new Integer.valueOf(28))
where id=1;
```

Comment: The above is not correct. You better spend more time in learning methods in `List`.

Comment: while this answer might be technically correct or wrong please explain what it's doing and why you think it would work